# Spring and hibernate persist() not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Hello I am developing a CMS using Spring and Hibernate. I have a page displaying existing products and a form which should add a new product to the database. However when I fill out the form and submit it nothing gets saved to the database. Additionally System.out.println does not print anything to the console so I have no idea where is the problem.

jsp page

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="productForm">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Product Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<form:input class="form-control"  type="text" id="productName" name="product name" path="name" />
<br></div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Serial number:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<form:input class="form-control" type="text" id="productSerial" name="serial number" path="serial" value=" " /></div></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveNewContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute("userForm") Product product,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    System.out.println(product);
    productService.saveOrUpdate(product);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

Service

```
@Override
public void saveProduct(Product product) {
    productDao.saveProduct(product);

}
```

DAO
the interface implementation has `@Transactional(readOnly = false)`

```
 public void saveNewProduct(Product product) {

    persist(product);   
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in the form just adding `action="saveNewContact"` fixed the issue.